# Qt build version from shared object

Tags: c++, qt, shared-objects

Suppose I have an executable that uses qt library. I want to replace the shared object with a custom one. So how do I find the qt version so that I can build it myself from source?

P.S. All the files has names like libQt5**.so.5.

Comment: For DLLs  right-click a DLL, go to properties, details, the version will be listed there. Maybe there is something similar in linux for so libs

Comment: @ddriver I use ubuntu 14.04. There's no such thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't own a very special setup the exact version is part of the lib name; all others are symlinks. E. g. installed here is Qt 4.8.1:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  680 Mai 27  2015 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Mai 27  2015 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so -> libQtCore.so.4.8.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Mai 27  2015 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 -> libQtCore.so.4.8.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Mai 27  2015 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8 -> libQtCore.so.4.8.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,9M Mai 27  2015 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4.8.1
```

Additionally the libs provide macros and functions to access the version at build and run time: [`QT_VERSION`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#QT_VERSION), `QT_VERSION_STR` and `qVersion()`.